# Pandas reading csv thousand seperator and nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
00:00;10.738,75;65;1.850;0;47.777
00:15;-;65;1.872;0;-
00:30;-;65;1.895;0;-
00:45;-;65;1.916;0;-
01:00;10.744,75;65;1.991;0;46.174
```

Since some of the data is only given every hour I want to interpolate it.

```
my_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_path,thousands='.',decimal=',',sep=';')
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.drop(['time'], axis = 1)
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.apply(pd.to_numeric)
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

I was expecting it to just save NAN, so that I can run the interpolate line next.
As a workaround I added the following line:

```
df_date = df_date.replace('-','0', regex=True)
```

But received the following error.
At that point a head already droped the time column so maybe the position is off.

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "10.738,75" at position 0
```

I would appreciate all tips on how to do this correctly.

Comment: Doesn't `read_csv` have a `na_values` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `na_values` parameter of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
my_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_path, thousands='.', decimal=',', sep=';', na_values='-')
```

Comment: Awesome. This works and for some reason now the thousand seperator does what it was supposed to.